# When to use const void*?

Tags: c, pointers, type-safety

I have this very simple test function that I'm using to figure out what's going on with the `const` qualifier.

```
int test(const int* dummy)
{
   *dummy = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

This one throws me an error with GCC 4.8.3.
Yet this one compiles:

```
int test(const int* dummy)
{
   *(char*)dummy = 1;
   return 0;
}
```

So it seems like the `const` qualifier works only if I use the argument without casting to another type.

Recently I've seen codes that used

```
test(const void* vpointer, ...)
```

At least for me, when I used `void *`, I tend to cast it to `char` for pointer arithmetic in stacks or for tracing. How can `const void` prevent subroutine functions from modifying the data at which `vpointer` is pointing?

Comment: `const T*` means that the data _pointed to_ by the pointer is const. The 2nd one is very fragile, since it casts away the const.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo But from what I've read on other stackoverflow posts, isn't const void* often used to prevent the data from being modified? But it seems to me that by casting it can be modified very easily.

Comment: @MoneyBall yes, but casting is like that. That's why casting is dangerous - I can take your "const int * " and cast it to "int64_t * "  and SIGSVF or corrupt other data. The problem is with the *casting* not the const declarations.

Comment: @Mσᶎ Right, I thought __const__ qualifier could prevent data from being modified. Turns out C lets you cast it and modify it without raising any errors.

Comment: Excuse my wording, but.... how stupid would it be if `const` would be working in case you cast something to an non constant type? Just imagine you have a given prototype for some callback or something which for internal purpose has the argument const. But in case you know YOUR implementation will never provide an const argument OR you are able to catch the case when it is, WHY should the compiler if you explicite by cast say it has not to be treat as constant anyway treat it as constant?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: The second one is even more fragile since it casts from int pointer to char pointer and changes so while the first example accesses at least 2 Bytes, the second example definetely just thats `dummy`'s first byte to be representing one. this could lead to a lot more trouble as just casting away an simple const qualifier which m8 be unnecessary anyway in that case.

Comment: @MoneyBall C lets you do many other dangerous things, like reading from / writing to any memory address you want (just assign a pointer to a random integer and dereference it), read / write past the end of an array and several others. If you want the compiler to prevents all of those things, you should pick another language. In return, you then give up a lot of the low-level control that C gives you which _can_ make programs written in it so blazingly fast.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
const int *var;
```

`const` is a **contract**. By receiving a `const int *` parameter, you "tell" the caller that you (the called function) will not modify the objects the pointer points to.

Your second example explicitly **breaks that contract** by casting away the const qualifier and then modifying the object pointed by the received pointer. Never ever do this.

This "contract" is enforced by the compiler. `*dummy = 1` won't compile. The cast is a way to bypass that, by telling the compiler that you really know what you are doing and to let you do it. Unfortunately the "I really know what I am doing" is usually not the case.

`const` can also be used by compiler to perform optimization it couldn't otherwise.

---

Undefined Behavior note:

Please note that while the cast itself is technically legal, modifying a value declared as `const` is Undefined Behavior. So technically, the original function is ok, as long as the pointer passed to it points to data declared mutable. Else it is Undefined Behavior.

<sub>more about this at the end of the post</sub>

---

As for motivation and use lets take the arguments of `strcpy` and `memcpy` functions:

```
char* strcpy( char* dest, const char* src );
void* memcpy( void* dest, const void* src, std::size_t count );
```

`strcpy` operates on char strings, `memcpy` operates on generic data. While I use strcpy as example, the following discussion is exactly the same for both, but with `char *` and `const char *` for `strcpy` and `void *` and `const void *` for `memcpy`:

`dest` is `char *` because in the buffer `dest` the function will put the copy. The function will modify the contents of this buffer, thus it is not const.

`src` is `const char *` because the function only reads the contents of the buffer `src`. It doesn't modify it.

Only by looking at the declaration of the function, a caller can assert all the above. By contract `strcpy` will not modify the content of the second buffer passed as argument.

---

`const` and `void` are orthogonal. That is all the discussion above about `const` applies to any type (`int`, `char`, `void`, ...)

`void *` is used in C for "generic" data.

---

Even more on Undefined Behavior:

Case 1:

```
int a = 24;
const int *cp_a = &a; // mutabale to const is perfectly legal. This is in effect
                      // a constant view (reference) into a mutable object

*(int *)cp_a = 10;    // Legal, because the object referenced (a)
                      // is declared as mutable
```

Case 2:

```
const int cb = 42;
const int *cp_cb = &cb;
*(int *)cp_cb = 10;    // Undefined Behavior.
                       // the write into a const object (cb here) is illegal.
```

I began with these examples because they are easier to understand. From here there is only one step to function arguments:

```
void foo(const int *cp) {
    *(int *)cp = 10;      // Legal in case 1. Undefined Behavior in case 2
}
```

Case 1:

```
int a = 0;
foo(&a);     // the write inside foo is legal
```

Case 2:

```
int const b = 0;
foo(&b);     // the write inside foo causes Undefined Behavior
```

Again I must emphasize: unless you really know what you are doing, and all the people working in the present and in the future on the code are experts and understand this, and you have a good motivation, unless all the above are met, **never cast away the constness!!**

Comment: First off, thank you for all the examples. It's clear to me that even though const establishes some sort of contract between the caller and the callee, callee can easily cast away the const qualifier. Would it be safe to say that const qualifier does NOT guarantee the value pointed by const void* pointer is constant?

Comment: @MoneyBall It is safe to say that C gives you methods to shoot yourself in the leg (allowing to cast away the const qualifier is one of them). That being said, it is safe to assume a function won't cast away the const qualifier. Unless it is a malicious or a bugged function.

Comment: @MoneyBall I added a note about the compiler enforcing this contract

Comment: You said that if callee receives __const__ __int*__ __vpointer__, the 4Bytes of data pointed by __vpointer__ is constant. So if __const__ is a **contract** between caller and callee, if callee is given __const__ __void*__, what does it mean? How does callee know how much data are constant?

Comment: @MoneyBall not the first object, all the objects.

Comment: Is there situations where __const__ __void*__ is preferred over __void*__? I can't think of a situation where I would use __const__ __void*__, or even __const__ __void*__ __const__.

Comment: "`const` and `void` are *orthogonal*" -- No, `const` and `void` do not appear at *right-angles* to one another and share no perpendicularity between them. Perhaps `const` and `void` are *unrelated* as one is a qualifier and one a type. Yes this is a nit, but there seems to be a growing "cute" misuse of orthogonal that has no place in technical writing.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin English is not my first language, so I might be wrong in its use, but "orthogonal" also has the meaning of "independent" http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/orthogonal , http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthogonal

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is the edit ok now? "const and void are not coupled"

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for fixing it. It helps keep the site technically correct.

Comment: @bolov: FWIW, the version with "orthogonal" was actually better (clearer) than the version with "not coupled". On any site with large numbers of well-educated, technically-minded people, you'll encounter a lot of claims about how words are "supposed" to be used, or what they "actually" mean. Many of these claims are completely wrong; and David C. Rankin's is one of them.

Comment: @Moneyball.  [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) is an example of using `void *` vs. `const void *`.  The parameters point to generic data.  A third parameter gives the size.  The source data is const, the destination data is not.

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> int test(const int* dummy)
> {
>    *(char*)dummy = 1;
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

No, this does not work. Casting away constness (with truly `const` data) is *undefined behavior* and your program will likely crash if, for example, the implementation put `const` data in ROM. The fact that "it works" doesn't change the fact that your code is ill-formed.

> At least for me, when I used void*, I tend to cast it to char* for
>   pointer arithmetic in stacks or for tracing. How can const void*
>   prevent subroutine functions from modifying the data at which vpointer
>   is pointing?

A `const void*` means a pointer to some data that cannot be changed. In order to read it, yes, you have to cast it to concrete types such as `char`. But I said *reading*, not *writing*, which, again, is UB.

This is covered more in depth [here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/EXP05-C.+Do+not+cast+away+a+const+qualification). C allows you to entirely bypass type-safety: it's your job to prevent that.

Comment: Actually casting away constness is not undefined behavior. It is well defined even to modify the value pointed by, with the condition that the object was declared mutable. See my answer for a detailed example. But I 100% agree that is not a reason to allow casting away constness

Comment: @bolov Yeah, thanks for pointing out. I sorta alluded to that when I mentioned an implementation that places `const` data in ROM.

Answer (score 4):

It’s possible that a given compiler on a given OS could put some of its `const` data in read-only memory pages.  If so, attempting to write to that location would fail in hardware, such as causing a general protection fault.

The `const` qualifier just means that writing there is **undefined behavior**.  This means the language standard allows the program to crash if you do (or anything else).  Despite that, C lets you shoot yourself in the foot if you think you know what you’re doing.

You can’t stop a subroutine from reinterpreting the bits you give it however it wants and running any machine instruction on them it wants.  The library function you’re calling might even be written in assembler.  But doing that to a `const` pointer is **undefined behavior**, and you really don’t want to invoke **undefined behavior**.

Off the top of my head, one rare example where it might make sense: suppose you’ve got a library that passes around handle parameters.  How does it generate and use them?  Internally, they might be pointers to data structures.  So that’s an application where you might `typedef const void* my_handle;` so the compiler will throw an error if your clients try to dereference it or do arithmetic on it by mistake, then cast it back to a pointer to your data structure inside your library functions.  It’s not the safest implementation, and you want to be careful about attackers who can pass arbitrary values to your library, but it’s very low-overhead.