# Undefined behaviour of const_cast when we return mutable object from class

Tags: c++

I am not sure about const_cast in this case. Do we have undefined behaviour or not?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A {
    mutable vector<int> a;
    A() : a(1,2) {}
    const vector<int>& get() const {
        return a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    vector<int> &b = const_cast<vector<int>&>( a.get() );
    b[0] = 3;
    cout << a.a[0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: dupe/related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe

Comment: the last part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34842262/2805305) is helpful to understand const casting and what you can and cannot do.

Answer (score 3):

Modifying a variable that is non-const is well defined. `const_cast` exists precisely to allow modification of a non-const object using a const reference (works similarly for volatile despite the name). There is no undefined behaviour in the example code.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to remove const from a reference to a variable that is non-const. In this case, `a` is non-const, `a.a` is non-const, so the `const_cast` is perfectly legal.

The `const_cast` is also a bad idea because it may result in class the invariant being violated behind its back. Modifications to the vector should be done through an appropriate public interface to the class.